# Помогите написать калькулятор со слайдером на jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

Всем привет. Начал делать калькулятор на jQuery и не выходит динамически изменять элементы. Формулы я прописал и сделал слайдер, но вот как теперь всё это заставить работать?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/KoXOML)

Вот код

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Расчёт</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-8">
            <div class="slider"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" disabled id="month"  value="3" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="procent"  value="0" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="percentage"  value="0" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-2">
            Всего:
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-4">
            <span class="price">3000</span> руб.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  function update() {  
      $price = 3000;
      $procent = $("#procent").val();
      $percentage = $price/100*$procent;
      $month = $("#month").val();
      $result = ($price + $percentage) / 24;
  }


$(function() {
        var valMap = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 18, 20, 24];
        $(".slider").slider({
            min: 3,
            max: valMap.length - 1,
            value: this.value,
            range: false,
            slide: function(event, ui) {                        
                $("#month").val(valMap[ui.value]);
        update();
            }       
        })
})

$('input#month').on('input', function(){
  if(+$(this).val() > 24) {
    $(this).val(24);
  }
  if(+$(this).val() < 3) {
    $(this).val(3);
  }
});

$('#month').on('click', function(){
   $( ".slider" ).slider( "value", this.value );
}).trigger('keyup');

$("#month").change(function(event) {
    jQuery('.price').html($result);
});

update()
});
```

Comment: А что калькулятор считать то должен? Тоесть какие вещи вы динамически не можете менять?

Comment: На https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/KoXOML пример же, что сделано. Мне нужно в слайдере указывать количество месяцев и  забивать в поля проценты и ещё сумма платежа, которая высчитывается по формуле и от этого должна изменяться цена <span class="price"></span>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всего лишь добавляете изменение цены в фунцкию update и все:

```
function update() { 
      $price = 3000;
      $procent = $("#procent").val();
      $percentage = $price/100*$procent;
      $month = $("#month").val();
      $result = ($price + $percentage) / 24;
    $('.price').html($result);
  }
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxqagj?editors=1111

Comment: Переделал калькулятор. Сейчас столкнулся с двумя проблемами: 1. Не обновляется поле `value` при перетаскивании ползунка. 2. У меня ячейка Ежемесячный платёж показывает 0 и ещё событие по полю Первоначальный взнос думаю повесить на `change`, чтобы при добавлении в это поле рандомного числа в поле Ежемесячный платёж был бы пересчёт значений, но не знаю как лучше сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну вообще тут не преветствуются двойные-тройные вопросы, но попробую помочь. Что это за поле, value? Насчет "платежей" не понял, так как таких полей у вас нет (по крайней мере в коде раньше не было)

Comment: Атрибут input с id="monthprice" `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="monthprice"  value="0" />`, Пробовал выводить его так `$('#monathprice').val($result.toFixed(2));` в console.log всё считается, а в форму не подставляется и не меняется, остаётся значение `value="0"`. В поле "Первоначальный взнос" если 0, то отображать в `$('#monathprice').val($result.toFixed(2));` если ввёл данные в это поле input, нужно чтобы сразу считало, алгоритм у переменной `$depositprice`. Тоесть цену минусуем на первоначальный взнос и плюсуем процент, который высчитывается от количества месяцев.

Comment: Так, я вижу, что monthprice меняется, вы все решили я понимаю?

Comment: Всё за исключением одной проблемы. Нужно настроить кнопки + и - которые должны считать месяцы по нашему массиву чтобы ползунок слайдера менялся и в поле input с id="month менялись эти самые месяцы https://codepen.io/sequelone/pen/XEZOdm

Comment: Вы програмно когда меняете положение слайдера (кнопками +/-) то не срабатывает событие `slide`. Или поймите как его вызывать в ручную (может быть `$slider.slide()`) или просто в обработчике нажатия на +/- добавьте обновление поля `#month` и функцию `update`. Если ответ на первоначальный вопрос дан, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как правильный (галочка под рейтингом ответа)